# Templates and type erasure - Why does this program compile?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, type-erasure

I have written an example type erasure program, but I noticed something that seemed strange. The code compiles - and I believe it shouldn't. More likely, it does something that I don't understand which enables it to compile.

Here is a MWE.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class Object
{
public:

    template<typename T>
    Object(T value)
        : p_data(std::make_unique<Model<T>>(std::move(value)))
    {

    }

    Object(const Object& object)
        : p_data(object.p_data->copy())
    {

    }

    Object(Object&& other) noexcept = default;

    Object& operator=(const Object& object)
    {
        Object tmp(object);
        *this = std::move(tmp);
        return *this;
    }

    Object& operator=(Object&& object) noexcept = default;

   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Object&);

private:

    struct Concept;
    std::unique_ptr<Concept> p_data;

    struct Concept
    {
        virtual
        ~Concept() = default;

        virtual
        std::unique_ptr<Concept> copy() const = 0;

        virtual
        void draw_internal(std::ostream&) const = 0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Model : public Concept
    {

        Model(T value)
            : data(std::move(value))
        {

        }

        std::unique_ptr<Concept> copy() const override
        {
            return std::make_unique<Model<T>>(data);
        }

        void draw_internal(std::ostream& os) const override
        {
            std::cout << "Model<T>::draw_internal(std::ostream& os)" << std::endl;
            os << data;
        }

        T data;
    };

};


//  This enables us to do
//      std::cout << Object
//  We forward the call to unique_ptr<Concept>::draw_internal using virtual function
//  dispatch
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Object& object)
{
    std::cout << "operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Object& object" << std::endl;

    object.p_data->draw_internal(os);
    return os;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<Object> document;

    document.push_back(0);
    document.push_back(std::string("Hello World"));

    std::cout << "Drawing now!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << document << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Actually this is a broken example—at runtime the code enters an infinite loop. No doubt for reasons related to the fact that it compiles when it (maybe) shouldn't.

Here's why I think it shouldn't compile:

- There is no `operator<<` defined for the type `std::vector<Object>`.

That said, I suspect this compiles, because the compiler is able to generate a compatible operator from something within this code. I just don't understand exactly how it has done this. My guess would be there is an implicit conversion from `std::vector<Object>` to `Object<T>` with `T=std::vector<Object>`? But this is really a guess.

- At runtime there is an infinite loop caused by `operator<<` calling itself. I don't understand exactly why this happens either.

Interestingly, here are two things which do not compile:

```
std::vector<int> a;
std::cout << a << std::endl;

std::vector<std::string> b;
std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

So the compiler clearly can't generate `operator<<` for any type. *This makes me think my guess about what is happening is wrong.*

It was compiled with GCC 12 ([Mingw-w64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingw-w64)) on Windows 10.

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISRqkrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIaZqQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/oGp6Y4CoeFRLLHxXIm2mPZFDEIETMQE2T5%2BATV1mY3NBCWRMXEJSQpNLW25nWN9A2UVIwCUtqhexMjsHOYAzGHI3lgA1Cbbbk5jxJisJ9gmGgCCO3sHmMenbCwkAJ43d49muwY%2By8RxObguYWAvweTyBLzebgAbpgHCRoY8YQ99kwFApDgB5aLaFEEP4mADsVgeyS80VoeGQIDJD0OrMOBEwLGSBg5YIIX2SjFYrwAKui2QSiSSICLDoixF5MIs/hKJSBDskAProJhNCBjdAgEAsJgAa0wmq8DDwAEdFWCALIYWpgsXbW7u/UEQ3G1DIiDy7xKxbKllsilUjH3CUUgAizOjbMJxIcEDQDDGkpTpLMADZDqgpQ5Q4nVYd1VqdXrC9mAHSV3VMAC0NzQyS%2BEBDKvDlITMfJ8cxpaz0uTJPMuYnBYICDii0ODFQmFUG2SBDescOWCoTC8tFJ20j3dZY4cU9QguIurR21jaYEmdPOfzNZJJf7kbLJ6L64IXIgr7Ficn5fgAVDOeB4icm4Gkanz%2Bn%2ByTKoex6qpcBBrAwhzgQgkHAahcZ9kmP7npe17ENBEBPhO54/vOi7Lqu67QVumA7nuB5HmGhxUMQeCuIcsEgGkBCXNceYFmRRAUacYJej6IliSwE6kIc6aPiRebIVx9zJHx8ockyQ4ShcXgOIcHhApga74dxgnekaVq2oqmprjJbiWUxNwatqja2VGJmiWZ66edZpJ2RGqESoieAtF4YhRWyAB%2BoVrp2G6sex%2B7%2BYlrIxXFCV2YFPpOXaFpuWCqUHtgakXh287qcxt6HBoOVFWy%2BUYYVw7RageDoFuV4AO6amEHLEMwtDyUailXMpWm1RmTWbq1KERQObXDhyXI8pgfICkKbCHG6tx2aZ5lOlgtDlhqtL0sgFkCF5606V%2BhyXbUMpygqSq5aq6pVkw02%2Bv6gaKl27WspFxlfoRMNlkJpUuRVpxVd5bb1YtmZ%2BnEfFYH90M9V%2B6GYfZPomualrWmVjrOrQrq/J6gPaQTG3w6qiJ9QN6DDaNghxJNwOzeJL4KA1D7rjjxB43tkPHL2cvFUaaBeE1bhgscZhmB99OnCdRo80wI1jQLYhCxcc3nmL5hmAiGtCa4usgW9rJpHbpxbn5a1E1DbMBV%2BsqA/5/bxt7MYwht3sJgA9NHrIirheJCnSmB4l4eJEFuqB/LHCMOSgqxqxr1EPLnhwAOqvPwxBDc0A0zq8oi0NdmdI%2BVomVU9YU3AbvMmxNYiHOnkJyrFXXXVQVoOJkOdx1ukHJLqyAIFDDxCcL80vlJN7q6c5uiZbElpKpjUjmeR90WSCvDkJKtFx7NsXnE5FgnJ68WyLBYKCfEtn8%2BBaaVtq/D2DsGDoCdkRV2P56y%2BSaC2d0htjb8wHlNNILM7Ikwml/HKfsExjUOCaMInYr7OzJkaZEqJ3LUXdFnZAPhGCcUgbQ%2Bhgh6zpwQJqaITBkCmggBodBw50CoDoWwVhNIFAcK4Tw4GEIjAQBtgACVqLQVAFcSC0HQDbLsUczr5zvu7NwmszCxmGiPRcQ0wBgBtgYshIBHbBzZLfQuNihEiIYTY0B4CHGsicarDx%2Bd7E6OHJgrCq0jwDg4MsWgnAACsvA/AcC0KQVAnB1aWGsIJVY6xXg7B4KQAgmhInLFNP4XMtZyS5g0BockVSYlmBidsAAnAEGJ%2BhOCSHiYU5JnBeAKBAIEApiTImkDgLAJAaAuR0DiOQSgEzkhTPiMALgZguB8DoONPpEBohdOiGEZoXxOB5ImaIgg%2BIGC0AOUM0gWATRGHEFc/Alxp7Ij6Vc5cKJVabDySbaJVz6TRCvMQL4HgsBdNEngFghzhlUAMMABQAA1fiQ18SCgSXk/gggRBiHYFIGQghFAqHUFc3QqyDBGBQNYaw%2Bg8DRD6ZAZYF56ivN6bUEkmQXBgMmH4ZZ0gQhhEGOUYYPKUhpAyAILlEhyQisKJkOYQxKhmGkHYNlAhegTE8O0CQiqugqoaOMfo/L5hCu1TMdVORuVStNQa0o8qtWSGWAoLJGw9AHy%2BcM35cTSAJKSSkjgqgAAcuYmy5kkIcYAyAHrLNrFwQ4EA0lWEsKpXAhASCa22Ksx6kz6DEDTVwRYvBBlaBDKQEpDTawAkaY0swlbJDkkkJUmJjTWm/I6V6rpvren9PyYU4tvyzCdKuR27tQzi3ImIOkZwkggA)

Comment: Change constructor `Object(T value)` to `explicit Object(T value)` to see where implicit conversions are happening in your code.  `std::cout << document` is invoking an implicit conversion.

Comment: @DrewDormann I thought about doing that but it prevents construction of any object. How would one enter any values into the vector to initialize it?

Comment: Ah ok, didn't realize I can just do `.push_back(Object(1))`. With that, the code then fails to compile, as you may expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out. Someone may correct me if this is wrong.

Starting from

```
cout << document
```

this is, in terms of the types involved

```
cout << vector<Object<T>>
```

This is implicitly converted to

```
cout << Object<vector<Object<T>>>
```

I'll just add this line, which we will refer back to later. Since `cout` is a type of `ostream`, we more precisely have this:

```
ostream << Object<vector<Object<T>>> // call this (A)
```

Looking at the function call for `operator<<(ostream&, Object<T>& object)` we can see that it does this:

```
[ operator<<(ostream&, Object<T>& object) ] :
    object.p_data->draw_internal(...)
```

Converting that to the type, we have this:

```
object.[unique_ptr<W>]->draw_internal(...)
```

with `W = Model<T>`, `T = vector<Object<U>>`.

So this is a function call to

```
Model<T>::draw_internal(ostream& os)
```

and `draw_internal` does this:

```
[ Model<T>::draw_internal(ostream& os) ] :
    os << data
```

where `data` is of type `T = vector<Object<U>>`. Therefore it is a function call like this:

```
os << vector<Object<U>>
```

Because of the implicit conversion we saw previously, the compiler actually converts this into

```
os << Object<vector<Object<U>>
```

In other words, it does this:

```
os << Object(data) // instead of just os << data
```

and hence we have a loop. `operator<<` is calling itself via `draw_internal`. See `(A)` above.

Answer (score 3):

You could have stripped your example down bit by bit to get to a MWE like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/99E19593e):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Object {
    template<typename T> Object(T) {}                              // #1
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Object&); // #2
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Object> document;
    std::cout << document << std::endl;
}
```

***I truly just removed pieces as long as the program would compile, stopping only when I couldn't reasonably remove anything else.***

Once got to this point it's easy to experiment and, in this specific situation, find out that commenting either `#1` or `#2` makes the program fail to compile.

The step is short to connect that to the solution to the question.

By they way, the suggestion in one of the comments to the question of using `explicit` really pays off.

Answer (score 2):

> There is no operator<< defined for the type std::vector.

Nearly any type is convertible to `Object` thanks to the constructor template here:

> ```cpp
> template<typename T>
> Object(T value)
>    : p_data(std::make_unique<Model<T>>(std::move(value)))
> {
> }
> ```

Thus this operator overload:

> ```cpp
> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Object& object)
> ```

Can take almost any argument

Comment: Hmm. Why can't it implicitly convert `vector<int>` to `Object<vector<int>>` when it can convert `vector<Object>` to `Object<vector<Object>>`?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant With `std::vector<Object>`, `operator<<(std::ostream&, const Object&)` can be found via ADL, since `Object` is in the global `::` namespace. With `std::vector<int>`, the only namespace looked at with ADL is `std::`, so `os << data;` only finds functions already declared at that point (like with a non-template function), so it can't find the `operator<<` declared in the future. If you move `Model<T>::draw_internal`'s (https://godbolt.org/z/jh5qxnqTs) definition down or declare the `operator<<` beforehand (https://godbolt.org/z/oh4sYP71s) then it would find it.